How to guarantee proper member function implementation in a class hierarchy
I currently have a class hierarchy that boils down to this:
class A
{
    int m_A = 1;
 public:
    void assign(const A& other)
       {
        m_A = other.m_A;
       }
};

class B : public A
{
    int m_B = 2;
 public:
    void assign(const B& other)
       {
        A::assign(other);
        m_B = other.m_B;
       }
};

class C : public B
{
    int m_C = 3;
 public:
    void assign(const C& other)
       {
        B::assign(other);
        m_C = other.m_C;
       }
};
//... and so on

That member function assign() copies (...) the content of another instance of the same type.
I discovered (with pain) that this has two major flaws: the program is (silently) incorrect if I forget to implement assign() in a subclass, or in its implementation forget to call the parent's ::assign():
class Berr1 : public A
{
    int m_Berr1 = 2;
 public:
    //void assign(const Berr1& other) // Oops!
};

class Berr2 : public A
{
    int m_Berr2 = 2;
 public:
    void assign(const Berr2& other)
       {
        //A::assign(other); // Oops!
        //...
       }
};

This is very brittle, and I wonder if there's a technique to guarantee that subclasses inheriting from A implement the member function assign() correctly, observing that:

The assign() member functions doesn't have the same prototype. Assigning a parent object (ex. A) to a child one (ex. B) is wrong and must cause a compilation error.
I'm not excluding CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) but I'd be more interested in alternative techniques (if existing)


Concepts can force assign() to be called with the same type but cannot prevent the mistake of failing to call the parent assign().

@Dai I think that a concept would just check if calling obj.assign(other); compiles

Assignment in a polymorphic hierarchy should be implemented this way: class Base { ... void operator=(const Base&) = delete; ... }. If the heierarchy is not polymorphic, it is a job for CRTP. If you are using C++23, the alternative technique would be the explicit object parameter.

Not messing with assignment would be an option. Seems like the default generated operator= would do exactly what the example function does.

You never have to create "assign" functions. The copy constructor and copy-assignment operator are already responsible of this. And in your case, the default ones already do the job, you have nothing to do, except removing all your assign functions :D

@Fareanor Good luck copying an object using copy constructors when you only have a reference to base class.

@Yksisarvinen in this case, a virtual clone function calling the copy constructor is required.

@Fareanor @BoP The assign I need isn't a default copy, I realized my simplified example is a little misleading, I should have renamed the function.

Is the nature of the actual function memberwise assignment or not? If not you may want to clarify what the function is supposed to do.

@WeijunZhou Working on it

@Yksisarvinen Yes but the class is not polymorphic so you should not try to use polymorphism with it. It would not make sense.

Is private inheritance out of the question?

@AndyG Nothing against private inheritance, can you explain?

If you use private inheritance, then nobody can accidentally call A::assign via e.g., B::assign if someone forgot to implement B::assign. A programmer forgetting to call the base class' assign function is not something that can be handled by a type system. You can make it easier for programmers by e.g., writing some utility that handles some boilerplate for them within assign, but then you'd still need to remember to use the utility ("utility" is a stand in for e.g., a macro or heck even a visitor pattern)

@AndyG Understood, I'll consider that

In your case, I think you need virtual classes, with a clone function calling the copy constructors. An assign function could be created in the same way. The copy constructors can not "forget" something. The job of a copy constructor is to be exhaustive or delegate to the default behaviour.
class A
{
  private:
    int m_a;
  public:
    A(int a) : m_a(a) {}
    A(A const&) = default;
    A(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(A const&) = default;
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;
    virtual A* clone() const { return new A(*this); }
};

class B : public A
{
  private:
    int m_b;
  public:
    B(int a, int b) : A(a), m_b(b) {}
    B(B const&) = default;
    B(B&&) = default;
    B& operator=(B const&) = default;
    B& operator=(B&&) = default;
    B* clone() const override { return new B(*this); }
};

class C : public B
{
  private:
    int m_c;
  public:
    C(int a, int b, int c) : B(a,b), m_c(c) {}
    C(C const&) = default;
    C(C&&) = default;
    C& operator=(C const&) = default;
    C& operator=(C&&) = default;
    C* clone() const override { return new C(*this); }
};


I simplified my example a little too much, but this would be absolutely reasonable in case I needed a copy.

I just updated the example but I think this answer remains helpful

@MatG FWIW you should not edit a question in a way that invalidates already existing answers.

@Fareanor Well, maybe a moderator could suggest if I have to undo the changes and repost? Let me try to auto-flag the question and ask for intervention

@MatG You can rollback yourself, you don't need a moderator. I would suggest to open a new question with the last edit :)

@Fareanor Rolled back, I'm unsure to repost an almost identical question though

@MatG For your actual problem, I think you can refactor your classes so that you have a vector in the base class A and it would contain all the values for the all hierachy. Each derived class could then add it's value into the vector at construction and, if you want, create a reference (or pointer would be better) member to the corresponding vector location where to find the value (e.g. int * m_A = &v[0]). Like that, only A should have the special_assign() fonction and all of them would inherit it with already the good implementation (since all it has to do is to copy the whole vector)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

At the risk of deviating too far from the question, there are reasons this fits poorly in C++.
First, if classes have an "is-a" relationship, which is public, unambiguous inheritance, it is exceptionally easy and implicit to use the derived as the base. This is baked into the language. Template deduction can deduce bases, references to derived implicitly convert to references to base, return types can depend covariantly on a reference within the hierarchy, etc.
If the base also has data and has behaviors on that data that differ from the behavior on derived, it is easy to produce bugs. This is as you already noticed. If base has data, and behaviors that only rely on that data and are not overridden, then composition is typically a better choice. The consequence is that a base class in a polymorphic relationship should define an interface and not have data.
Second, the representation is a salient part of the type. Therefore, replacing one choice of polymorphic behavior with another (as in assign or a copy) needs a level of indirection. The polymorphic type must either work with allocated implementations to support the dynamic size, or be sized as large as the largest one to be used (e.g. as in variant).
One can see how this interacts with assign. The following operations are meaningful but perform different actions (to avoid bugs, they should be the same):
B b1, b2;
b1.assign(b2);                  // (1) copies as B
static_cast<A&>(b1).assign(b2); // (2) copies as A

Furthermore, it should be obvious that there's no way to statically catch this because if assign is called on an A&, that might not be a B or related to it. So what does it mean to assign a B to an unrelated (by inheritance) type D?
In a way, the initial question is a category error. There really is an interface (A::assign), but that interface is impossible to implement.
So a less problematic implementation would look like:
// The polymorphic type, can represent one of several implementations
//
// One could directly use a reference instead, but one gets neither
// move or copy operations, so it is good for non-owning uses, but
// poorer for owning uses. One could instead use a pointer or
// std::reference_wrapper, which can be put into containers.
//
// Or, one could use a unique_ptr<A>, which is reasonable for owning
// uses, but does not have copy operations. And usage requires
// indirection.
//
// Or, one could use a variant<B, C, ...> if the collection of
// implementations is a closed, known set. However, users must then
// perform the visitation.
//
// If one wants an owning type, supporting copies, the most user-friendly
// option is a wrapper type to handle the indirection. That wrapper can
// wrap either a unique_ptr or variant depending on whether the set of
// implementations is open or closed. This is of course a trade-off,
// because it is better for the users but more work for the initial
// author.
//
// When using a unique_ptr, there is the advantage that is very close
// to pimpl, a technique for reducing compile times and achieving ABI
// stability.
class A
{
public:
    struct Impl;

    // To use pimpl, this is the main thing that would need to
    // change: e.g. to a factory method. Everything else would
    // just need to move implementation to the cpp.
    template <std::derived_from<Impl> T>
    A(const T& t) : m_impl(std::make_unique<T>(t)) { }

    A(const A& other);
    A& operator=(const A&);
    A(A&&) noexcept;
    A& operator=(A&&) noexcept;
    ~A();

    // Let's add a function to the interface, since we'll make
    // assignment just *do the right thing* and we don't need assign:
    auto name() const -> std::string;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};

// This is the base type. Note: it is a pure interface, as
// outlined above, with no data. Also note: by using pure
// virtual member functions, we can guarantee that there is
// no forgetting to implement one.
struct A::Impl {
    virtual auto clone() const -> std::unique_ptr<A::Impl> = 0;
    virtual auto name() const -> std::string = 0;
};

// Special member functions. Copy needs implementations.
A::A(const A& other) : m_impl(other.m_impl->clone()) { }
A& A::operator=(const A& other) {
    m_impl = other.m_impl->clone();
    return *this;
}
A::A(A&&) noexcept = default;
A& A::operator=(A&&) noexcept = default;
A::~A() = default;
auto A::name() const -> std::string {
    return m_impl->name();
}

class Berr1 : public A::Impl {
public:
    auto clone() const -> std::unique_ptr<A::Impl> override {
        return std::make_unique<Berr1>(*this);
    }
    auto name() const -> std::string override {
        return "Berr1";
    }

private:
    int m_Berr1 = 1;
};

class Berr2 : public A::Impl {
public:
    auto clone() const -> std::unique_ptr<A::Impl> override {
        return std::make_unique<Berr2>(*this);
    }
    auto name() const -> std::string override {
        return "Berr2";
    }

private:
    int m_Berr2 = 2;
};

Berr1 berr1; // berr1.name() == "Berr1"
Berr2 berr2; // berr2.name() == "Berr2"
berr1 = berr2; // error, by design there isn't a relationship here

// But with the polymorphic container
A a1{berr1}; // a1.name() == "Berr1"
A a2{berr2}; // a2.name() == "Berr2"
a1 = a2; // allowed, changes a1 from representing Berr1 to Berr2

// The polymorphic container is an ordinary type
std::vector<A> v1{a1, a2};
auto v2 = v1; // make a copy

See godbolt.

I had to read this twice. Unfortunately my actual code is a little more complicated than my simplified (and contrived) example, but you convinced me to rethink my design
